# Show current amount of users on my website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there any php, javascript, or ajax that can add a count to my website to show current users online? When users are online it changes the text value, and when users leave change the text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find very much plugins for this in the internet

for example: http://www.hit-counts.com/

http://www.bestfreecounter.com/?gclid=CPWYrs7-1r0CFRCWtAodmyMAlQ
    http://www.simplehitcounter.com/

Or if you want a tutorial for this, to write it on your own:

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Simple-hit-counter-using-php/42461

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current number of users online (rather than the total number of hits to your page), you'll need to track it on the server side - increment a value every time someone logs in, decrement it every time someone logs out.

However... on the web, it's not always easy to tell if someone has logged out. They could just close their browser and walk away. So you'll need to keep track of activity: if a user's session has expired, then they can be considered logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your user moves his/her cursor(or some other sign of activity), send an ajax request to a PHP file, which can count the number of users that sent such ajax request in the last 10 seconds. it can then return this value which can be displayed as the counter.